# check for no value before my onclicklistener

Tags: android

What is the best practice for checking in an EditText for any values before my onclick from a button is fired off.  When its fired off now with no value it errors out and crashes.  I tried to do a if(edittext != null){then my onlcick code} and it still crashed when I clicked it after no value in the edittext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `if (edittext != null) {...}` does not work is because this statement will check for a condition on the actual `EditText` object, and not its contents.

If you're after the contents, simply call `edittext.getText()` and apply your validation logic to that. There's a convenience method in [`TextUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html) that you can use to check whether the text is `null` or empty (`""`): `TextUtils.isEmpty(edittext.getText())`. You can use it for plain Java strings too, e.g.

```
TextUtils.isEmpty(edittext.getText().toString().trim())
```

Which will trim leading and trailing spaces first, before the test. Depending on your requirements, you can extend this easily with a regular expression to strip out any white space character etc. As a general tip: search around for "android form validation" and I'm sure you'll find more pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I used this:

```
String content = editText.getText().toString().trim();
if (content.length() == 0) {
    // do something
}
```

Since this also prevents strings with only whitespaces.